# Problem with Multiple Dotted Lines using Loop Repeats

Tags: counters, loops, for-loop

I am trying to use the "loop repeat" to write multiple dotted lines as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}


\setlength\dashlinedash{0.3pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

%newcommand for one dotted horizontal line
\newcommand\aline{\hspace{420pt} \\
     \hdashline \\}

%newcommand for multiple dotted horizontal line
\newcommand{\dlines}[1]{
\newcounter{int}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\vspace{8pt}
    \setcounter{int}{0}
    \loop
    \aline
    \addtocounter{int}{1}
    \ifnum\value{int}<10
    \repeat
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
\dlines{10}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the file, the loop stops at the first iteration and giving me one dotted lines only. However, If I remove the code "\aline" and replace it with "\theint", the loop works and giving me the output "0123456789".

It seems that something in the command "\aline"  is stopping the iteration but I have no idea why.
Is there any way to fix this problem? Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: after the first iteration you insert `\\ `  which ends the group so `\loop` loses all its state and can not iterate. The counter assignment is global but `\loop` itself uses local assignments to define its iteration.